# fbcp reads wrong primary display resolution (RPi2)

Tags: hdmi, video, framebuffer

I'm trying to use [fbcp](https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) to mirror /dev/fb0 (the built in framebuffer) to /dev/fb1 however i just cannot get a picture with the native resolution of /dev/fb1 (320x240). I tried different settings in /boot/config.txt (i'm only stating the difference from default):

boot/config.txt:

```
framebuffer_width=320, framebuffer_height=240
disable_overscan=1
```

/var/log/messages:

```
Kernel command line: ... bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=320 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=240
fbcp[2113]: Primary display is 720 x 480
```

---

and a second try:

/boot/config.txt

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080 
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=13  # 240p
```

/var/log/messages:

```
Kernel command line: ... bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=720 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=240
fbcp[2116]: Primary display is 720 x 240
```

---

All this seems very inconsistent to me.

Edit: this might actually be a firmware bug. I have submitted a bug-report here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

framebuffer_width/height only set's the resolution of the text console.

hdmi_mode 13 is 720x240, what you are seeing is correct, I had the same initial dramas however found some information on how to set 320x240 using a custom mode:

Add the below to your config.txt file:

```
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
```

https://github.com/watterott/RPi-Display/blob/master/docu/FAQ.md